# How to get document cookies in Ionic Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

The app stores data in cookies after successful login. I need to retrieve the data back for another reason but I am unable to get it with the following JS command.

```
document.cookie
```

Is there any way to get the cookie? I tested the app in the desktop browser and can see the cookie stored in the browser's local storage.

I use the Ionic native HTTP plugin.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

Comment: check this link "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service"

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the information about the cookie here, but if the cookie is HttpOnly it cannot be accessed by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP plugin has a method to get the cookie as a string.

The following is an example of how to get the cookie.

```
this.httpNative.getCookiesString(url);
```

In the param, need to pass a URL for which we need to retrieve the cookie.